# How to make USE for class quickly in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm, hotkeys

How i can quickly make

```
use \DateTime;
```

for `new \DateTime();`
in PhpStorm ? I saw on some videos guys do that with some hotkey or something like that.

Comment: `Alt+Enter` (on Windows/Linux) when caret is on problematic place (or by clicking on the light bulb icon) is the shortcut to bring a menu with intentions and quick fixes.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the most relevant contextual options with secondary mouse click. The one you want is **Show Context Actions** (you'll see your current keyboard shortcut beside, mine is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>):

[image: Context menu]

Additionally, clicking on the code and waiting for a second will often display a standalone light bulb that points to the same command:

[image: Light bulb]

Those are called [intentions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/intention-actions.html). There're two that apply here:

- Replace with alias (to add `use foo as bar;`)
- Simplify FQN (to just add `use foo` or remove it altogether if already in root namespace)

Your particular example is a strange use case (you only save one character worth of typing) but the feature rocks when you have nested namespaces.